# test class failure in production alone

Tags: apex

I have a test class part like below.

```
custom_Object__c capStore = [
  SELECT Id, custome_feild__c
  FROM custom_Object__c 
  LIMIT 1];
```

Now it passes in all other sandboxes and fails only in production org while deploying. I have verified access levels and it is all good. can anyone suggest why this would be happening

Comment: Without more context, we really can't help you. Are you using SeeAllData=true? What kind of object is it? Did you make sure to insert the appropriate record first?

Comment: I am not using SeeAllData=true. it is an custom object . The records are present in it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that your Outbound Changeset has ALL required components included.

I ran into this issue before when trying to deploy a Trigger.

I was moving a  changeset that contained a QuoteTriggerHelper class, but I failed to bring in QuoteTrigger as well. I was getting stuck at 6% coverage in production even though I was at 89% in the sandbox.

I uploaded a new changeset with ALL the required components (in my case I was just missing QuoteTrigger) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `custom_Object__c` is empty at the moment of this line execution.

With empty sObject this line will generate a error

```
custom_Object__c capStore = [
  SELECT Id, custome_feild__c
  FROM custom_Object__c 
  LIMIT 1];
```

With empty sObject this line will generate a empty list

```
list<custom_Object__c> capStore = [
  SELECT Id, custome_feild__c
  FROM custom_Object__c 
  LIMIT 1];
```